# Change Preview file settings in Azure Deployment Center

Tags: azure, azure-functions, github-actions, continuous-deployment, azure-deployment

I'm trying to set up CD for Github Actions via Azure Deployment Center. All is good until I get to review of my Preview File, there is one setting I wanna change there, does anyone have an idea how to maybe override or change it manually? 
I've read that the best option to copy content of this file and past it to github actions and make changes there, but I wonder maybe someone know better ways

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample Function App in portal and tried to deploy the code using `Deployment Center` - `GIT`.

- AFAIK, I don`t see any options to edit the workflow in the Azure Portal.

[image]

- Once you save the GitHub settings, `.github/workflows` folder will be created in the `GIT Repository`.

[image]

- Open the workflows folder and edit the workflow manually.
  [image]

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment?tabs=github#how-the-github-actions-build-provider-works), the only option available to update the workflow is from GIT Repository.